# const values instantiation perfomance inside a method C#

Tags: c#, constants

Is it performance normal to use constants inside a method in C#?

I mean are there any benefits in using constants as class attributes over using constants as variables inside a method?

If I write

```
class C {
   void f() {
     const int i = 0;
   }
}
```

will it be slower than

```
class C {
  const int i = 0;
  void f() {}
}
```

?

Will in the first case variable `i` get instantiated every time I call `f()`? Or will it be instantiated only once during compilation?

Comment: Every instance of the member marked as const will be replaced with its value during compilation, regardless of the location of its declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will in the first case variable i get instantiated every time I call f()? Or will it be instantiated only once during compilation?

The easiest thing is to try it. For example, compile this code:

```
using System;

class Test
{
    const int ClassConst = 10;

    static void PrintLocalConst()
    {
        const int LocalConst = 10;
        Console.WriteLine(LocalConst);
        Console.WriteLine(LocalConst);
    }

    static void PrintClassConst()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ClassConst);
        Console.WriteLine(ClassConst);
    }
}
```

Both methods are compiled to the same IL:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  PrintLocalConst() cil managed
{
  // Code size       18 (0x12)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_0003:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0008:  nop
  IL_0009:  ldc.i4.s   10
  IL_000b:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Console::WriteLine(int32)
  IL_0010:  nop
  IL_0011:  ret
} // end of method Test::PrintLocalConst
```

There's no value on the stack for the local constant; instead, every time it's used, the constant value is included directly in the IL - hence `ldc.i4.s 10` being used twice.

To that extent, a local const is *very, very, very slightly* more efficient than a class const, because the class const is still represented in the IL. The local const is effectively completely removed by the compiler. But a few bytes for a constant in the IL representation is incredibly unlikely to ever be significant. (It's not allocated on a per object basis, or per method call.)